# Computing Pushed forward measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> For $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^{2}+1$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure, compute the pushed forward measure $f_{*} \lambda$ and compute $\int_{[1,2]} e^{\sqrt{x-1}} d\left(f_{*} \lambda\right)$.

Solution: We have for $a, b>1$, $f_{*} \lambda((a, b])=\lambda\left(f^{-1}(a, b]\right)=\sqrt{b-1}-\sqrt{a-1}$. Any other half interval would be $f_{*} \lambda((a, b])=f_{*} \lambda((a, b] \cap[1, \infty))$. We can thus conclude that $f_{*} \lambda(A)=\lambda_{F}(A \cap[1, \infty))$, where $F(x)=\sqrt{x-1}$. For the second bit, $\int_{[1,2]} e^{\sqrt{x-1}} f_{*} \lambda(d x)=\int 1_{[1,2]}(f(t)) e^{t} d t=e^{1}-1$
from the tool we defined to compute integrals with respect to pushed forward measure. We could also use the tool of integral with respect to a L-S measure:
$\int_{[1,2]} e^{\sqrt{x-1}} f_{*} \lambda(d x)=\int_{[1,2]} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x-1}} e^{\sqrt{x-1}} \lambda(d x)$.

Question:

1. This may seem like a silly question. But isn't $f_{*} \lambda((a, b])=\lambda\left(f^{-1}(a, b]\right)=2\sqrt{b-1}-2\sqrt{a-1}$? Am I missing something here?
2. I think the 'tool' used in $\int_{[1,2]} e^{\sqrt{x-1}} f_{*} \lambda(d x)=\int 1_{[1,2]}(f(t)) e^{t} d t=e^{1}-1$ is the change of variable formula, that I asked about [Changing variables of integration (transfer lemma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939809/changing-variables-of-integration-transfer-lemma). Could anyone help me understand why this implies the above step?

Thanks!

Comment: $2\sqrt{b-1}-2\sqrt {a-1}$ is correct.